# Go to a bookmark that is not visible currently due to narrowing

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, bookmarks

Running emacs 25.2.2 spacemacs 0.200.13.

In an org file, I have defined several bookmarks(SPC f b) under different headings. Consider this:

```
* H1
  Some text
  Bookmark 1
* H2
  Some text
  Bookmark 2
```

Suppose I am in H1 narrowed and I `SPC f b Bookmark 2`, nothing happens.

Similarly, if I am in another buffer and I jump to Bookmark 2 when the buffer is narrowed to H1, I just switch buffer!

How do I tell emacs to adjust narrowing such that the bookmarked location is visible?

Comment: I guess you need to find out what command SPC f b runs, and put an advice before it to widen the buffer.

Comment: @JohnKitchin `SPC f b` runs `helm-filtered-bookmarks`. This just lists all bookmarks and one can  select the one needed by typing a few characters, like other helm functions. Also, a noob here. So, will you please tell me what advice do I add and how? I have checked this (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html#Advising-Functions) only to get confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a lot trickier than I would have imagined. Here is the advice I finally came up with that seems to do what you want.

```
(defun widen-dwim (orig-func &rest args)
  (let* ((bmk-record (car args))
     (file (bookmark-get-filename bmk-record)))
    (when file 
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
    (widen)))
    (apply orig-func args)
    (when (string= "org" (file-name-extension (buffer-file-name)))
      (org-show-entry))))

(advice-add 'bookmark-default-handler :around 'widen-dwim)
```

Comment: Note that `bmkp-goto-position` is a function in [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus). You may want to post equivalent or similar code that uses only what is in vanilla `bookmark.el`, for people who do not want/need features offered by Bookmark+

Comment: Good point. I updated the code. It works for me in a vanilla emacs.

Comment: @JohnKitchin Perfect. It now goes to the bookmark as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If these are ordinary Emacs bookmarks, not something different, then you should be able to add a function to `bookmark-after-jump-hook`, to show the hidden stuff.

I'm no Org expert, but here's one suggestion:

```
(add-hook 'bookmark-after-jump-hook 'org-bookmark-jump-unhide)
```

Comment: thanks. Yes. These are ordinary Emacs bookmarks, `C-x r l` shows these bookmarks. I tried your suggestion but it does not work. The cursor now goes to the end of narrowed region. Anything else that I might try?

Comment: Dunno. I don't use Org (ducks...). Do you mean that the cursor goes to the end of the narrowed region, which stays narrowed? If so, then clearly `org-bookmark-jump-unhide` is not the right function. But its doc says, at least, "Unhide the current position, to show the bookmark location." And it calls `org-show-context`, whose doc says, "Make sure point and context are visible..."

Comment: I am pretty sure org-bookmark-jump-unhide only deals with unhiding folded headings. That hook also happens too late to help with the narrowing issue.